# Devise log in and unauthorise right after

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following scenario:

I log in my rails application using Devise:

```
DEBUG[006797c6]     I, [2014-06-05T15:18:08.225548 #447]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 212.194.198.62 at 2014-06-05 15:18:08 +0000
DEBUG[006797c6]     I, [2014-06-05T15:18:08.228152 #447]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
DEBUG[006797c6]     I, [2014-06-05T15:18:08.228330 #447]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zObTwp85xx+YFcSuY/d4fPcCHp7sDiYvNWlCFjf81gg=", "user"=>{"email"=>"olivier.milla@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

which works and I get redirected where appropriate:

```
DEBUG[006797c6]     I, [2014-06-05T15:18:09.447824 #447]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://www.white.eu.com/dashboard
DEBUG[006797c6]     I, [2014-06-05T15:18:09.448024 #447]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 1220ms
DEBUG[006797c6]     I, [2014-06-05T15:18:09.527190 #447]  INFO -- : Started GET "/dashboard" for 212.194.198.62 at 2014-06-05 15:18:09 +0000
DEBUG[006797c6]     I, [2014-06-05T15:18:09.531336 #447]  INFO -- : Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
```

from which I get Unauthorized right after:

```
DEBUG[006797c6]     I, [2014-06-05T15:18:09.532996 #447]  INFO -- : Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

Obviously my `before_filter :authenticate_user! in dashboardController` steps in to kick the user out.

My `User` resource is:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
```

I see no reason for this to happen. There is no csrf check.

Any input on this? I use rails 4.1.1 with Devise 3.2.4.

============== EDIT ==============

```
class DashboardController < ApiController
  helper :all
  def index
  end    
end

class ApiController < ApplicationController
  unless Rails.application.secrets.SKIP_DEVISE_IN_DEVELOPMENT && Rails.env.development?
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your dashboardController code and if you have override any devise controllers or methods then can you post them as well?

Comment: I added dashboard controller code and relevant methods.

Comment: (I did not override Devise's SessionsController)

Comment: Are you sure it's authenticate_user filter which is kicking user out? Remove it and try to run after that and what is this line doing "unless Rails.application.secrets.SKIP_DEVISE_IN_DEVELOPMENT && Rails.env.development?"

Comment: But server is in production mode so this lines does nothing. (It's a general lock to allow devs to workin in development without devise kicking in). Let me try without the line and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I removed the :authenticate_user! call and I can log in just fine.